Faces Subtraction where a subface being subtracted from main face
[Given ABCD and WXYZ two rectangles] (https://i.sstatic.net/AJ6JCNt8.png)
Suppose you have two faces: Main and subface as it is previewed in the upper image. How to compute vertices of the 8 faces that resulted in subtraction?
Note that the vertices are 3D and not 2D.
Anticipated Output; 8 new faces

I attempted through vectors lines intersection, and it felt right but it was too much computation and calculations needed.

I've tried to use geometry perspective into reality where I can use resemblance of triangles or rectangles, but my mind went nuts after few attempts.


I'm seeking for a general quick way each rectangle(face).
Here it is my attempt in c# code - Notes before code:
1. Face is considered to be an entity that holds 6 indexes where are 4 indexes are unique. The 6 vertices are dual triangle that depicts a quad face of a mesh.
2. I might be computing some mistakes - so if you notice some, i would be glad for any help. [This is not my final solution]
3. I'm asking here to seek for a better solution if I may find. gist.github.com/RagnarokFate/8df399d61398a27f63493d7d9f30ead8

Map the coordinates to a 2D plane with axes of adjacent sides of the outer rectangle, then it's pretty trivial.

i honestly forgot that i can map vertices into simpler 2d plane lol. thanks! i thought at first Interpolation would be a quicker way to solve this but i am not a big fan of math

Right, always simplify the problem as much as you can. Since you said rectangles, can we assume that both rectangles are somehow axis aligned to "something"? Either the world or any local space? Are both axis aligned to the same coordinate space or can one be "rotated" in some way? Is the smaller one always enclosed in the larger one or can they somehow overlap? The answers to those question make a huge difference on the approach and outcome. Usually you only need to project the points of the inner rect onto the sides / vectors of the outer rect.
